# Getting `No NgModule metadata found for 'class{}'` error when building angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, module

In my angular app, I have multiple modules. I moved all the components from AppModule to MainModule(new one). Now I imported the MainModule in AppModule. Everything is working fine when I run the application using `ng serve`. But when I run `ng build --prod`, I am getting the following issue.

[image]

My module files are:

**AppModule:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MainModule } from './main.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    MainModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and

**MainModule:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SharedModule } from './modules/shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccountDetailsComponent } from './pages/account-details/account-details.component';
import { KPIsComponent } from './components/kpis/kpis.component';
import { ConsentActivitiesComponent } from './components/consent-activities/consent-activities.component';
import { AccountsListComponent } from './components/accounts-list/accounts-list.component';
import { AccountCardComponent } from './components/account-card/account-card.component';
import { CardCommonLayoutComponent } from './components/card-common-layout/card-common-layout.component';
import { LinkedAccountsComponent } from './components/linked-accounts/linked-accounts.component';
import { StepperNavComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/stepper-nav/stepper-nav.component';
import { FIListComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/fi-list/fi-list.component';
import { DiscoverAccountsComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/discover-accounts/discover-accounts.component'
import { LinkAccountsComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/link-accounts/link-accounts.component'
import { AccountDashboardComponent } from './pages/account-dashboard/account-dashboard.component';
import { AccountActionComponent } from './components/account-action/account-action.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './pages/profile/profile.component';
import { PageWrapperComponent } from './pages/recent-activities/page-wrapper/page-wrapper.component';
import { ChangePinComponent } from './pages/change-pin/change-pin.component';
import { FilterDropdownComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/filter-dropdown/filter-dropdown.component'
import { LinkAccountComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/link-account/link-account.component';
import { DiscoverAccountComponent } from './pages/account-link/components/discover-account/discover-account.component'
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LinkingStepperComponent } from './pages/account-link/linking-stepper/linking-stepper.component';
import { AccountLinkingIntroScreenComponent } from './components/account-linking-intro-screen/account-linking-intro-screen.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ...   
    LinkAccountComponent,
    DiscoverAccountComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ...
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

**main.ts:**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { LibrModule } from './app/libr.module';
import 'zone.js';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

if(environment.library) {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MainModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
} else {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

I don't understand the actual issue. Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks...

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: Angular: 8.2.14

Comment: Try removing the empty `providers: []` arrays from your modules.

Comment: Try changing your app.module.ts by for example removing a curly bracket and the putting it back. Then save the edit.

Comment: @MattU, trie that. No luck

Comment: @samga, trie that too. Same issue.

Comment: Can you share your `main.ts` as well?

Comment: see daniloagostinho's answer on this page:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798

Comment: @MattU Will update answer

Comment: What is `LibrModule`?

Comment: LibrModule is MainModule. Anyway I corrected the update. Please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error cases, I found that the if condition in `main.ts` is causing the issue. After removing the if condition and put it normally, everything working fine.

I changed this

```
if(environment.library) {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MainModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
} else {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

to this (Still not sure, why above is not working)

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MainModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And I also moved the if condition to the `angular.json` file. In that file, I created another object under configuration and in that, I added my conditions in `fileReplacements` as below

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.lib.ts"
    },
    {
        "replace": "src/main.ts",
        "with": "src/main.lib.ts"
    }
],
```

As above, I achieved the conditional loading of `main.ts` file.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks...